# Do you have to create a new document to access File menu and go to options?

Tags: microsoft-word

In Office 2013, Word, I cannot access any menu regarding Word's options.

I must create a new document then the menus are there.

I specifically need to access File to see Activation Status and Options.

Is this just my version or it is that "complicated" way now? Why would they require to create a new document just to access Word's options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't access Backstage (the File menu) without a document open. You have two options, either create a blank document and access Backstage or turn off the Office 2013 Start Screen so that a blank document always loads.

**Turn off Office 2013 Start Screen**

Open a blank document

Go to **File** > **Options**

In the **General** section, the option **Show the Start Screen when this application starts** is at the bottom of the list of options. **Uncheck** this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I think that in 2010 it was always a new doc open, right? Maybe I forgot that. I followed the turn off of the start screen.

Comment: Yes, I believe in Office 2010 the default was to open with a blank document.